# Compilation error creating System::Threading::Tasks in C++/CLI. Unable to spot the error

Tags: c++-cli, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to make a C++/CLI wrapper layer (that calls into an unmanaged C++ DLL) expose functions that return `Task<T>` to my C# layer.    The unmanaged functions are expensive which is why I wanted asynchronous versions.

But I can't get it to build.

My approach is to use TaskFactory::StartNew in C++/CLI supplying a System::Func 
 that takes one argument and returns one value.  The prototype of that, in MSDN is as follows:

```
StartNew<TResult>(Func<Object,TResult>, Object)
```

(It seems I *must* use this if I want my created task to pass arguments into my expensive, synchronous function.  I make "Object" contain all the args I need, wrapped up into some internal class.  My code can unpack it and use them.)

Below is a simple C++/CLI example I tried to whip up to show the problem.  And below that are the errors I get.  I have clearly identified the failing line with "THIS LINE FAILS".  There's also another line that shows with red Squiggly in Visual Studio but doesn't cause a compiler error.

The code (This is all in VS 2017)

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;

namespace CppCliLayer
{
// Arguments class.  Because TaskFactory.StartNew only appears to allow us one
// argument to our task function, at best (a System::Object).  This packs up the
// multiple arguments we'll need

public ref class Arguments
{
    String^ string;
    int     intVal;
public:
    Arguments(String^ s, int n) { string = s; intVal = n; }

    property String^  Text  { String^ get() { return string; } }
    property int      Token { int     get() { return intVal; } }
};

// "Expensive": Want to return an instance of this from a long running task..
public ref class Expensive
{
public:
    static Expensive^ CreateExpensively(Arguments^)
    {
        // Do slow stuff with arguments, then create. 
        // <Imagine slow synchronous code here....>

        return gcnew Expensive();
    }
};

// Function that takes a long time to create an instance of Expensive

Task<Expensive^>^ ExpensivelyCreateAsync(String^ s, int n)
{
    auto func = gcnew Func<Arguments^, Expensive^>(&Expensive::CreateExpensively);  // *** VS UNDERLINES THIS WITH A SQUIGGLY (see below for more)
    auto args = gcnew Arguments(s, n);
    return TaskFactory::StartNew<Expensive^>(func, args);  // *** THIS LINE FAILS
}

}
```

And the errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CppCliLayer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>testcli.cpp
1>d:\dev\testcli.cpp(130): error C2665: 'System::Threading::Tasks::TaskFactory::StartNew': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
1>d:\dev\testcli.cpp(130): note: could be 'System::Threading::Tasks::Task<CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^System::Threading::Tasks::TaskFactory::StartNew<CppCliLayer::Expensive^>(System::Func<System::Object ^,CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^,System::Object ^)'
1>d:\dev\testcli.cpp(130): note: or       'System::Threading::Tasks::Task<CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^System::Threading::Tasks::TaskFactory::StartNew<CppCliLayer::Expensive^>(System::Func<CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^,System::Threading::Tasks::TaskCreationOptions)'
1>d:\dev\testcli.cpp(130): note: or       'System::Threading::Tasks::Task<CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^System::Threading::Tasks::TaskFactory::StartNew<CppCliLayer::Expensive^>(System::Func<CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^,System::Threading::CancellationToken)'
1>d:\dev\testcli.cpp(130): note: while trying to match the argument list '(System::Func<CppCliLayer::Arguments ^,CppCliLayer::Expensive ^> ^, CppCliLayer::Arguments ^)'
1>Done building project "testcli_v15.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
StopOnFirstBuildError: Build cancelled because project "corecli_v15" failed to build.
Build has been canceled.
```

I should mention that my C++/CLI dll is targeting.NET Framework 4.6.2 
I should also mention that the compiler underlines this line with a red squiggly

```
auto func = gcnew Func<Arguments^, Expensive^>(&Expensive::CreateExpensively);
```

and the message it gives me when I hover over it is "expected a type specifier".  But it does not generate a compilation error.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It must be `Func<Object^, Expensive^>.  The intellisense parser bug is, well, ugh.  Task is very little joy in C++/CLI, you found a good reason to move this code into a C# library.

Answer (score -1):

The async function `CreateExpensively` function can only take in `Object` as parameter, it cannot take in other objects like `Arguments`. You can cast `Arguments` to `Object` in `CreateExpensively().`
Instead of using `TaskFactory::StartNew`, create a new instance of `Task`.
The red squiggly I believe is an intellisense parser bug, I see it in my VS2017 too.
The working code is as below:

```
// "Expensive": Want to return an instance of this from a long running task..
public ref class Expensive
{
public:
    static Expensive^ CreateExpensively(Object^ argObj)
    {
        Arguments^ args = (Arguments^) argObj;  // you can pass it Arguments here
        // Do slow stuff with arguments, then create. 
        // <Imagine slow synchronous code here....>

        return gcnew Expensive();
    }

    Task<Expensive^>^ ExpensivelyCreateAsync(String^ s, int n)
    {
        auto func = gcnew Func<Object^, Expensive^>(&Expensive::CreateExpensively);
        Arguments^ args = gcnew Arguments(s, n);

        // Use Task instead of StartNew
        Task<Expensive^>^ asyncTask = gcnew Task<Expensive^>(func, args);
        asyncTask->Start();
        return asyncTask;
    }
};
```